# Overloading + operator in c++ and the use of const

Tags: c++

This function returns a const Matrix A when I plus a Matrix B and C. But then I should not be able to change that const Matrix, for example `A = A + D;`, but I am. Could someone explain to me why that is possible?

```
const Matrix operator+(const Matrix&) const;
```

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ maybe the duplicate is a little far-fetched this time. I'm not asking for reopen, not going "against" you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A + D` creates a new `Matrix` instance without changing `A` but the problem here is that you're assigning it back to `A`.

The *assignment operator* changes `A`, not your addition operator. The `const` property cannot extend to the full expression.

Comment: So what is the use of const in that specific operator? I saw it on some slides on a google search and I am wondering why they chose to use const

Comment: it returns a constant object, but it is immediately passed to the assignment operator, which takes the left-side object as non-const and changes it.